# Return value of variables that is not null

Tags: python, variables, null

what is the best way in python to return the value of 3 variables, that is not null.
only 1 of the variable will not be null at any time.

so far i am using this non efficient code

```
if kwargs.get('F06_yes_1'):
    context1.update({'F06_1': kwargs['F06_yes_1']})
elif kwargs.get('F06_no_1'):
    context1.update({'F06_1': kwargs['F06_no_1']})
else:
    context1.update({'F06_1': kwargs['F06_na_1']})
```

Furthermore, to do the replacement (based on your comments), you can try:

```
context1.update({
    'F06_1': ('yes' if kwargs['F06_yes_1'] else None)
             or ('no' if kwargs['F06_no_1'] else None)
             or ('n/a' if kwargs['F06_na_1'] else None)
})
```

further to the answer provided below, when F06_yes_1 value is null, and F06_no_1 value is "on" i get the following error:

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\cherrypy\_cprequest.py", line 670, in respond
    response.body = self.handler()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\cherrypy\lib\encoding.py", line 217, in __call__
    self.body = self.oldhandler(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\cherrypy\_cpdispatch.py", line 60, in __call__
    return self.callable(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "example.py", line 872, in RPC_submit
    'F06_1': ('yes' if kwargs['F06_yes_1'] else None)
KeyError: 'F06_yes_1'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The or operation will select the first non-None value.

```
context1.update({
    'F06_1': kwargs['F06_yes_1'] 
             or kwargs['F06_no_1'] 
             or kwargs['F06_na_1'] 
})
```

Furthermore, to do the replacement (based on your comments), you can try:

```
context1.update({
    'F06_1': ('yes' if kwargs.get('F06_yes_1', None) else None)
             or ('no' if kwargs.get('F06_no_1', None) else None)
             or ('n/a' if kwargs.get('F06_na_1', None) else None)
})
```

You're getting the KeyError because you're trying to lookup a record that doesn't exist. To handle this more elegantly, you can use the .get method with a second argument which acts as the default return value if the key doesn't exist.

Comment: Great, thanks, let say the value returned is on, how can i efficiently change it no Yes

Comment: or best, if the value returned for the fist argument is on, how can i change it to yes and likewise for the seconf argument if not null, how can i change from on to No, again for the third argument from on to NA.

Comment: @Ossama see my updated post - you should rather update your question with these comments.

Comment: using the update  code for the above comment i get the following error when F06_yes_1 is Null and F06_no_1 is not Null context1.update({
    'F06_1': ('yes' if kwargs['F06_yes_1'] else None)
             or ('no' if kwargs['F06_no_1'] else None)
             or ('n/a' if kwargs['F06_na_1'] else None)
})

Comment: @Ossama, not sure what your error is, can you post the traceback in your original question please?