# Manipulation of returned argument

Tags: python, data-manipulation

Relevant to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46292549/return-value-of-variables-that-is-not-null#46292624)

How can I use the following code,  so if the value returned for the first argument "**F06_yes_1**" is "**on**", how can i change it to "**yes**"

and likewise for the second argument "**F06_no_1**" if not null, how can I change from "**on**" to "**No**",

and again for the third argument "**F06_na_1**" from "**on**" to "**NA**"

```
context1.update({
    'F06_1': kwargs['F06_yes_1'] \
             or kwargs['F06_no_1'] \
             or kwargs['F06_na_1'] \
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the following code if "F06_yes_1" is "on", then it will be "yes"

if "F06_no_1" not null, then it will be "No",

and if "F06_na_1" not null, it will "NA"

```
def is_on(arg):
    return arg == 'on'

context1.update({
    'F06_1': ('yes' if is_on(kwargs.get('F06_yes_1', None) else None)
             or ('No' if is_on(kwargs.get('F06_no_1', None)) else None)
             or ('NA' if is_on(kwargs.get('F06_na_1', None)) else None)
})
```

Comment: using the code for the above answer i get the following error when F06_yes_1 is Null and F06_no_1 is not Null context1.update({ 'F06_1': ('yes' if kwargs['F06_yes_1'] else None) or ('no' if kwargs['F06_no_1'] else None) or ('n/a' if kwargs['F06_na_1'] else None) })

Comment: when F06_yes_1 value is null, and F06_no_1 value is "on" i ge the following error:                            
    response.body = self.handler()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\cherrypy\lib\encoding.py", line 217, in __call__
    self.body = self.oldhandler(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\cherrypy\_cpdispatch.py", line 60, in __call__
    return self.callable(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "example.py", line 872, in RPC_submit
    'F06_1': ('yes' if is_on(kwargs['F06_yes_1']) else None)
KeyError: 'F06_yes_1'

Comment: it answered your question you have asked. it's better if you give more information in question.